# EKS DNS accessible inside private subnet

Tags: dns, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, openvpn, amazon-eks

The question is: How to expose DNS names pointing to the EKS cluster. DNS should only available inside our subnets and accessible with our VPN connection (which essentially means that DNS should point to addresses inside our VPC)

I have an EKS cluster which runs in the `10.0.0.0/16` VPC. Nodes are located inside private subnets, and services are exposed externally with ELB and Ingress Controller.

Since some of the services inside the VPC are only accessible inside of our company we have decided to runa OpenVPN server configured with routing to the `10.0.0.0/16` through the VPN and rest of the traffic going directly to the Internet. Currently public DNS configured in Route53 points to our private addresses which is not ideal. (ex A record for `privateservice.example.com` -> `10.0.1.1`). It is not ideal (existence of the `privateservice` shouldn't be available in a public DNS) but worked for now.

To resolve the problem of private services in a public DNS I though about running Bind DNS server and configuring our OpenVPN to push this configuration to clients (couldn't get it to work on some client machines but I assume it will work).

However I have no idea how to expose some private services running inside EKS cluster. As mentioned before there are some services in the cluster which are available publicly through ELB. But in the same cluster I have a subset of services which should be available only inside our subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use private hosted zone of route 53 for private DNS resovling. It should be better using internal ELB to expose services in EKS.
2. Use route53 resovler for resolving aws managed DNS in on-perms.

Comment: That's actually correct. Short after writing this message I've managed to do it this way, tested it and seems to work for the last couple of days. For the reference of others route53 private DNS IP is the second IP address of your vpc. (for exmaple 10.0.0.2 for 10.0.0.0/16)